# PHP: How to update/extend an multidimensional Array recursive and on-the-fly?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, recursion, multidimensional-array

I've a **multidimensional array** and would like to **update/add** some values, **recursive**. I'd like to avoid building a new array, if possible. But I've two **main problems**:

1. How to update the values "on-the-fly"? It should be possible with the `&-operator`.
2. How to get values to extend the array if the function `getDetails()` is out of scope.

My alternative is to rebuild everything, but I think there should be a more clean possibility.

I've added some pseudocode and hope it's not too weird. I appreciate your help!

Here's the fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/m2g-ign

**PHP**

```
// build the array 
$myArray = array(
    array(
        "id"   => 1,
        "name" => "A (Level 1)",
        "children" => array(
            array(
                "id"   => 3,
                "name" => "C (Level 2)",
                "children" => array(
                    "id"   => 4,
                    "name" => "D (Level 3)",
                    "children" => null  
                )
            ),              
            array(
                "id"   => 6,
                "name" => "F (Level 2)",
                "children" => array(
                    "id"   => 7,
                    "name" => "G (Level 3)",
                    "children" => null  
                )
            )   
        )
    ),
    array(
        "id"   => 2,
        "name" => "B (Level 1)",
        "children" => array(
            array(
                "id"   => 5,
                "name" => "E (Level 2)",
                "children" => null
            )
        )
    )
);    

// returns detailed data, important: it's out of scope
function getDetails($id) {
    // select dataset from DB
    // ...
    return $details;
}

// loop the array
$RAI = new RecursiveArrayIterator($myArray);
function updateMyArray($iterator) {
    while ($iterator->valid()) {
        if ($iterator->hasChildren()) {
            // recursive
            updateMyArray($iterator->getChildren());
        } else {
            /*
                // 1. set "name" to uppercase
                // Pseudocode:
                $iterator->activeChild()->change(function(&$value) {
                    $value = toUpperCase($value);
                });

                // 2. add Array
                // Pseudocode:
                $id = $iterator->activeChild()->getValue("id");
                $iterator->activeChild()->add("details", getDetails($id));     // getDetails() is out of scope, I guess
            */
        }
        $iterator->next();
    }
}    

echo "<strong>Before:</strong><pre>";
print_r($myArray);
echo "</pre>";

iterator_apply($RAI, 'updateMyArray', array($RAI));
echo "<strong>After:</strong><pre>";
print_r($myArray);
echo "</pre>";
```